# Openstack snapshot create and restore scripting with bash commands

Tags: bash, openstack

First of all it amazes me there is so little information about openstack and script examples but that is not the question i have

I want to create a snapshot and an simple way to restore the snapshot. Because the way of our hosting provider uses underlying storage i am unable to use the rebuild command so i need to destroy the running vm and recreate it with the snapshot image as a base. The creation of the image only works when all information about the running vm is provided as input parameters and here comes the troubles i have.

the information needed is provided by 3 commands

**command1: nova show 
Output:**
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property                             | Value                                                                                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NWFINFRA_1600 network                | 10.0.0.39                                                                                                                                                        |
| OS-DCF:diskConfig                    | MANUAL                                                                                                                                                           |
| OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone          | gn3a                                                                                                                                                             |
| OS-EXT-STS:power_state               | 1                                                                                                                                                                |
| OS-EXT-STS:task_state                | -                                                                                                                                                                |
| OS-EXT-STS:vm_state                  | active                                                                                                                                                           |
| OS-SRV-USG:launched_at               | 2019-10-02T14:25:21.000000                                                                                                                                       |
| OS-SRV-USG:terminated_at             | -                                                                                                                                                                |
| accessIPv4                           |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| accessIPv6                           |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| config_drive                         |                                                                                                                                                                  |
| created                              | 2019-10-02T14:25:05Z                                                                                                                                             |
| description                          | -                                                                                                                                                                |
| flavor:disk                          | 0                                                                                                                                                                |
| flavor:ephemeral                     | 0                                                                                                                                                                |
| flavor:extra_specs                   | {"ostype": "win", "hw:cpu_cores": "1", "hw:cpu_sockets": "2"}                                                                                                    |
| flavor:original_name                 | win.2large                                                                                                                                                       |
| flavor:ram                           | 8192                                                                                                                                                             |
| flavor:swap                          | 0                                                                                                                                                                |
| flavor:vcpus                         | 2                                                                                                                                                                |
| hostId                               | 18aa94c61106a53b2d9e672e93619a6fce76abb1ee6ba9da471491f9                                                                                                         |
| id                                   | 70941fbf-9143-4f1c-a5e7-979f818ace23                                                                                                                             |
| image                                | IFW039-InstanceSnapshot (8ee1104d-55e4-4c99-93e5-ceb4a53ce13f)                                                                                                   |
| key_name                             | -                                                                                                                                                                |
| locked                               | False                                                                                                                                                            |
| metadata                             | {}                                                                                                                                                               |
| name                                 | IWF039                                                                                                                                                           |
| os-extended-volumes:volumes_attached | [{"id": "1134fe12-777b-4c26-ac2b-e6ecb6ad4f70", "delete_on_termination": false}, {"id": "f610a46e-46ad-460f-81b3-e2b34acfbbfc", "delete_on_termination": false}] |
| progress                             | 0                                                                                                                                                                |
| status                               | ACTIVE                                                                                                                                                           |
| tags                                 | []                                                                                                                                                               |
| tenant_id                            | 4c15fd467dde4bd6a25427d6bab64a7f                                                                                                                                 |
| trusted_image_certificates           | -                                                                                                                                                                |
| updated                              | 2019-10-02T14:25:21Z                                                                                                                                             |
| user_id                              | ddff2ce854114bef873bac9a1476805e                                                                                                                                 |
+--------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

**Command 2: ./Scripts/openstack port show NWFINFRA_1600_IWF039
where NWFINFRA_1600_IWF039 is a combination of previous output NWFINFRA_1600 network and the server name IWF039**
Output:
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field                   | Value                                                                                                                                                               |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| admin_state_up          | UP                                                                                                                                                                  |
| allowed_address_pairs   |                                                                                                                                                                     |
| binding_host_id         | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| binding_profile         | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| binding_vif_details     | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| binding_vif_type        | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| binding_vnic_type       | normal                                                                                                                                                              |
| created_at              | 2019-10-02T06:49:08Z                                                                                                                                                |
| data_plane_status       | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| description             |                                                                                                                                                                     |
| device_id               | 70941fbf-9143-4f1c-a5e7-979f818ace23                                                                                                                                |
| device_owner            | compute:gn3a                                                                                                                                                        |
| dns_assignment          | fqdn='iwf039.rijkscloud.local.', hostname='iwf039', ip_address='10.0.0.39'                                                                                          |
| dns_domain              |                                                                                                                                                                     |
| dns_name                | iwf039                                                                                                                                                              |
| extra_dhcp_opts         |                                                                                                                                                                     |
| fixed_ips               | ip_address='10.0.0.39', subnet_id='3298e8d0-b317-465c-8757-c1a4f2cad298'                                                                                            |
| id                      | b49a7d3a-bb0d-49cb-a04b-64c5dbf9df20                                                                                                                                |
| location                | cloud='', project.domain_id='default', project.domain_name=, project.id='4c15fd467dde4bd6a25427d6bab64a7f', project.name='vws-pgb', region_name='Groningen3', zone= |
| mac_address             | fa:16:3e:99:cc:3c                                                                                                                                                   |
| name                    | NWFINFRA_1600_IWF039                                                                                                                                                |
| network_id              | 450dcc7a-5e55-4e38-9f4e-de9a9c685502                                                                                                                                |
| port_security_enabled   | False                                                                                                                                                               |
| project_id              | 4c15fd467dde4bd6a25427d6bab64a7f                                                                                                                                    |
| propagate_uplink_status | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| qos_policy_id           | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| resource_request        | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| revision_number         | 15                                                                                                                                                                  |
| security_group_ids      |                                                                                                                                                                     |
| status                  | ACTIVE                                                                                                                                                              |
| tags                    |                                                                                                                                                                     |
| trunk_details           | None                                                                                                                                                                |
| updated_at              | 2019-10-03T11:10:00Z                                                                                                                                                |
+-------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

with these outputs i can create the build command to restore the snapshot:
**nova boot --poll --flavor win.2large --image IFW039-InstanceSnapshot --security-groups default --availability-zone gn3a --nic net-id=450dcc7a-5e55-4e38-9f4e-de9a9c685502 IWF039**

note: the image is the name of the created snapshot

I try to script this so i can have a simple snapshot create and restore procedure

but i get stuck on the table layout of the output. This shows really nice but i cannot use it in my scripting to redirect the output to input variables.

I tryed using this: { read foo ; read ID Name MAC IP status;} < <(./Scripts/openstack port list --server IWF039 | sed 's/+--------------------------------------+----------------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------- +//' | sed 's/|//' | sed 's/MAC Address/MAC/' | sed 's/Fixed IP Addresses/IP/')

But the variables get contents like '|' char etc.

So echo $Name gives '|' as output.

There must be a simpler way but i am unable to see it.

Please help ...

I managed to get it almost working by using awk instead of grep:

i have now this code:
`#/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                   #                                                                                                                                                                                                                            # Query needed variables                                                                                                                                                                                                     #                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         echo -e "\nQuery needed information"                                                                                                                                                                                         NETWORK=$(nova show IWF039 | awk '/network/ {print $2}')                                                                                                                                                                     ZONE=$(nova show IWF039 | awk '/OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone/ {print $4}')                                                                                                                                                    FLAVOR=$(nova show IWF039 | awk '/flavor:original_name/ {print $4}')                                                                                                                                                         SERVERID=$(nova show IWF039 | awk -F '|' '/id/ {print $3; exit}')                                                                                                                                                            NETWORKPORT=$(nova interface-list IWF039 | awk -F '|' '/ACTIVE/ {print $3}')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              # Print out variables                                                                                                                                                                                                        echo "network: $NETWORK"                                                                                                                                                                                                     echo "zone: $ZONE"                                                                                                                                                                                                           echo "flavor: $FLAVOR"                                                                                                                                                                                                       echo "server_id: $SERVERID"                                                                                                                                                                                                  echo "network_port_id: $NETWORKPORT"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      # Remove current instance                                                                                                                                                                                                    echo -e "\nRemove current instance"                                                                                                                                                                                          nova delete $SERVERID                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     # Rebuild instance from snapshot image                                                                                                                                                                                       echo -e "\nRebuild instance from snapshot"                                                                                                                                                                                   nova boot --poll --flavor $FLAVOR --image IFW039-InstanceSnapshot2 --security-groups default --availability-zone $ZONE --nic port-id=$NETWORKPORT IWF039`

If i run the script the last item however e.g. IWF039 which is the name of the instance i want to use throws me an error: 
error: unrecognized arguments: IWF039

anyone can tell me why ?

If i run the line on the commandline it works, only not from the bash script

Comment: i found the answer inn using awk instead of grep

Answer (score 0):

```
#/bin/bash

#
# Script restores snapshot created in OpenStack
# Script created by Lex IT, Alex Flora
# usage: snapshot-restore.sh <snapshot image name> <server name to restore to>
# to use: make sure to install the following python openstack modules: 
# pip install python-openstackclient python-keystoneclient python-glanceclient python-novaclient python-neutronclient
#


#
# Query needed variables
#

if [ "$#" -eq  "0" ]
    then
        echo -e "usage: restore_snapshot <name of snapshot> <name of server>"
        echo -e "Querying available snapshots, one moment please ..."
        glance image-list

        echo -e "\n\033[0;33mGive name of snapshot to restore"
        echo -e "\033[0m"
        read SNAPSHOT

        echo -e "\n\033[0;33mGive server name to restore"
        echo -e "\033[0m"
        read SERVER
    else
        SNAPSHOT=$1
        SERVER=$2
fi

echo -e "\n\033[0mQuery needed server information from server $SERVER, one moment please ..."
NETWORK=$(nova show IWF039 | awk '/network/ {print $2}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
ZONE=$(nova show IWF039 | awk '/OS-EXT-AZ:availability_zone/ {print $4}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
FLAVOR=$(nova show IWF039 | awk '/flavor:original_name/ {print $4}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
SERVERID=$(nova show IWF039 | awk -F '|' '/\<id\>/ {print $3; exit}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')
NETWORKPORT=$(nova interface-list IWF039 | awk -F '|' '/ACTIVE/ {print $3}' | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//')

# Print out variables
echo -e "\033[0mnetwork: \033[0;32m$NETWORK"
echo -e "\033[0mzone: \033[0;32m$ZONE"
echo -e "\033[0mflavor: \033[0;32m$FLAVOR"
echo -e "\033[0mserver_id: \033[0;32m$SERVERID"
echo -e "\033[0mnetwork_port_id: \033[0;32m$NETWORKPORT"
echo -e "\033[0mSnapshot image: \033[0;32m$SNAPSHOT"
echo -e "\033[0mServer naam: \033[0;32m$SERVER"

# Ask confirmation
echo -e "\n\033[0mGoing to restore snapshot image $SNAPSHOT to server $SERVER"
read -p "Is this correct (y/n) ? " -n 1 -r

if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
    # Remove current instance
    echo -e "\n\033[0mRemove current instance"
    nova delete $SERVERID
    sleep 3
    # Rebuild instance from snapshot image
    echo -e "\nRebuild instance from snapshot using command:"
    echo -e "\033[0mnova boot --poll --flavor $FLAVOR --image $SNAPSHOT --security-groups default --availability-zone $ZONE --nic port-id=$NETWORKPORT $SERVER"
    nova boot --poll --flavor $FLAVOR --image $SNAPSHOT --security-groups default --availability-zone $ZONE --nic port-id=$NETWORKPORT $SERVER
fi
```

This is my complete script. Problem was that the output contained spaces in front of the string. I resolved this with the following sed command: `sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//'`

Hopefully someone has some use of the script.